# Jest "No Environment is configured" problem when import a javascript file,which uses environemnt variables

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am using jest to write unit test for my javascript functions (running with nodejs), I am very new to jest, if someone out here can help me, it will be appreciated!
Here are the situations:
file1.js is the file with functions I need to test, it includes some functions/statement that using environemnt varaibles.
file1.test.js is the testing file for file1.js

when I use const file1 = require("file1.js"), it complains "No Environment is Configured."

I did the following:
const OLD_ENV = process.env;

```
beforeEach(() => 
{
    jest.resetModules(); // most important - it clears the cache
    process.env = { ...OLD_ENV }; // make a copy
});

afterAll(() => 
{
    process.env = OLD_ENV; // restore old env
});
```

But it does not help.
I tried to do something like this:

```
test("simple test", ()=>
{
    const file1 = require("file1.js");
    ...
    expect(...)
});
```

It also have same problem.

Anyone have any thought?
Thanks, Gordon

Comment: Can you post the full error stack?

Comment: I have to put something like process.env.MyCustomName = value at beginning of the *.test.js file. But my question is now, why does it work if I put the same line of code in jest.config.js, it will not work?